# Disable filtering for a specific column in UI-Grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have a column in my grid which is contains several buttons. I want to only disable the filtering feature in that column.

For example, filtering should be available in office phone but It has to disable in Actions column. **I want to remove the textbox in Actions column**.

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set **enableFiltering:false** on the Actions field

for example:

```
 { 
      field: '', enableFiltering: false
 }
```

Comment: thanks to replay, I edit my question please see the bold part of my question

Comment: Has anyone got this to work? I can't find any reference to `enableFiltering` in the docs or the codebase

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `filterHeaderTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-filter-container"></div>'`

```
columnDefs: [{
    name: 'Name',
    type: 'string',
    filter: {
        condition: uiGridConstants.filter.CONTAINS,
    },
    filterHeaderTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-filter-container"></div>'
}]
```

This will not disable the filter feature, but will remove the input box so that user won' t be able to filter by entering txt